# PL/SQL How return all attributes in ROW

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, insert, sql-returning

I don't know how I can return all attributes with the RETURNING clause

I want something like this:

```
DECLARE  
    v_user USER%ROWTYPE  
 BEGIN  
     INSERT INTO User 
     VALUES (1,'Bill','QWERTY') 
     RETURNING * INTO v_user;  
END;
```

`RETURNING * INTO` gets an error , how can I replace `*` ?

Comment: side note: it's possible in PostgreSQL - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820789/oracle-equivalent-of-postgresql-insert-returning

Comment: @filiprem: and in Postgres you don't even need a procedural block for that. It can be used in plain SQL which is *much* more convenient.

Answer (score 6):

It would be neat if we could do something like that but alas:

```
SQL> declare
  2      v_row t23%rowtype;
  3  begin
  4      insert into t23
  5          values (my_seq.nextval, 'Daisy Head Maisy')
  6          returning * into v_row;
  7  end;
  8  /
        returning * into v_row;
                  *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-06550: line 6, column 19:
PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored


SQL>
```

I believe there may be a logged change request for this feature, because I know lots of people want it.  But for the moment all we can do is the long-winded specification of every column:

```
SQL> declare
  2      v_row t23%rowtype;
  3  begin
  4      insert into t23
  5          values (my_seq.nextval, 'Daisy Head Maisy')
  6          returning id, person_name into v_row;
  7  end;
  8  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Bad news if you have a lot of columns!

I suspect the rationale is, most tables have relatively few derived columns (sequence assigned to an ID, sysdate assigned to a CREATED_DATE, etc) so most values should already be known (or at least knowable) to the inserting process.

**edit**

> I was care how returning all
>   attributes without long-winded
>   specification of every column ;) Maybe
>   it's impossible.

I thought I had made it clear, but anyway: yes currently it is impossible to use `*` or some similar unspecific mechanism in a RETURNING clause.

Comment: Thx for reply. 
I knew that your example is good but I was care how returning all attributes without long-winded specification of every column ;)
Maybe it's impossible. Thanks for time

Comment: Documentation states 
"returning_clause can retrieve column expressions"
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_9014.htm#BABJFHEF

* (or table_alias.*) is specific to SELECT
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_10002.htm#i2080424

Answer (score 0):

So far the best solution I believe could be:

```
DECLARE  
    v_user USER%ROWTYPE;
    rowid_v rowid;
 BEGIN  
     INSERT INTO User 
     VALUES (1,'Bill','QWERTY') 
     RETURNING ROWID INTO rowid_v; 

     SELECT * INTO v_user WHERE rowid = rowid_v ;
END;
```

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml-returning-into-clause

Unfortunately, still there is no such functionality as returning * or returning row :) but will be cool.