# Error INSERT INTO ... RETURNING row into table

Tags: oracle, plsql, dml

I'm trying to return the inserting row into a table of ROWTYPE in PL/SQL but I have the error:

> ORA-00936: missing expression.

Table type declaration in package head:

```
  TYPE t_retourResult IS TABLE OF RESULTATS%ROWTYPE;
```

And error at inserting in the package body:

```
PROCEDURE EncoderResultats(p_tResultats IN t_resultats, p_tAjoutes OUT t_retourResult, p_tErreurs OUT t_erreur)
    IS
      ExceptTResultats EXCEPTION;
      i INTEGER;
    BEGIN
      IF(p_tResultats.COUNT = 0) THEN RAISE ExceptTResultats; END IF;

      FORALL i IN INDICES OF p_tResultats SAVE EXCEPTIONS
        INSERT INTO RESULATS VALUES p_tResultats(i) RETURNING * BULK COLLECT INTO p_tAjoutes;

      COMMIT;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN ExceptTResultats THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20006,'Le tableau est vide, aucun resultat à ajouter');
        WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE;    
    END EncoderResultats;
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a typo error in

INSERT INTO RESULATS VALUES p_tResultats(i) RETURNING * BULK COLLECT INTO p_tAjoutes;

it is not the table RESULATS but "RESULTATS"

moreover i guess you can't use "RETURNING * " , you have to specify all the column names as reported also here:
[PL/SQL How return all attributes in ROW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889250/pl-sql-how-return-all-attributes-in-row)